# Create multiple bucket in s3 using ANSIBLE-PLAYBOOK

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

i want to create multiple s3 bucket using ansible. Upload an object/dir in the created buckets (which is working in terraform) and a file (i think it is not working in terraform - with more than 1 bucket).
Is there any chance doing these in ansible?

I'm just new using ansible, i just read documentations and watching some videos.
Here are my basic data that being gathered.

```yaml
---
- name: create s3 bucket
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  vars_files:
    - creds.yml
  tasks:
  - name: create a simple s3 bucket
    amazon.aws.s3_bucket:
      name: kevs-task2-ansible
      state: present
      region: ap-southeast-1
      acl: public-read
      versnioning: enabled

  - name: create folder in the bucket
    amazon.aws.aws_s3:
      bucket: kevs-task2-ansible
      object: /public
      mode: create
      acl: public-read

  - name: create file in the folder
    amazon.aws.aws_s3:
      bucket: kevs-task2-ansible
      object: /public/info.txt
      src: info.txt
      mode: put
```

Comment: Looks like you just add another task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell and super simple:

```yaml
  - name: create a simple s3 bucket
    amazon.aws.s3_bucket:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
      region: ap-southeast-1
      acl: public-read
      versionning: enabled
   loop:
     - kevs-task2-ansible
     - an_other_name
     - yet_an_other_one
```

To enhance that, please read [ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html)